# Shouldn't the review be before the probation period ends?

Tags: probation

I have a probation period in my contract of 6 months. The only mention in my contract about this is:

During the first 6 months you will be in a probation period. Your employment with the Company may be terminated by either party giving the other at least **one week** written notice during your probationary period. Thereafter both parties may terminate employment by giving at least **one month**'s written notice.

I've completed my 6 months and I have a scheduled review in 2 weeks time. If I fail the review, shouldn't I receive the 1 month notice instead of 1 week because I'm over 6 months in employment?

Comment: If you were going to fail, I don't think they would wait two weeks.

Comment: It's a good example of how contracts are unfortunately worth almost nothing.  Say they did fire you, and gave you only one week's notice.  Or - one day's notice.  What, in fact, would you do?  Sue them?  Unfortunately no legal practice would take your case, as there would be no chance of any significant renumeration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you were going to fail the review, chances are you'd already know about it.  As you've passed the six-month time period, then as per the contract the one calendar month notice period is now in effect.

Comment: Agreed. Since you passed your probation without incident, it's unlikely your employer would bring up something _now_. It's probably just a normal performance review, where you and your employer review how things went during your probation and what could be improved towards the future.

Comment: The review is still happening because it isn't going to be just telling you that you've passed the probation. They will want to give you feedback on where your strengths and weaknesses are.

Answer (score 6):

Your contract doens't seem to mention anything about waiting for a review. If you're past the six-months period, you're out of probation, and you can legally require the one-month notice if things go south at the review.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, and it is indeed correct the author could "require" the company give him a 1 month notice (per the terms of the contract).  Being able to enforce that clause will be tough if the company has decided the author has in fact not passed the probation period, basically a judge would have to decide which party wins (since the contract does not specifically indicate that case).  However, as written, it leans towards the 1-month notice.

Comment: Yes, you're right, i've emphasized too much that "legally".